# Ошибка Post https://formm.ru/handler.php: EOF

Tags: post, golang

Ошибка исполнения `panic: Post https://formm.ru/handler.php: EOF`, не могу понять почему он выдает.

```golang
form := url.Values {
    "username": {"Jack"},
}

proxyUrl, err := url.Parse(mass[bproxy]) //массив с прокси серверами
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Ok")
}

httpClient := &http.Client { Transport: &http.Transport { Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl) } }

bclose := bytes.NewBufferString(form.Encode())
httpr, err := httpClient.Post(host, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", bclose)
httpr.Close = true;

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Почитал что `EOF` может быть из-за того что сервер не вернул полные заголовки или из-за того что соединение закрывается до завершения заголовка. То есть может быть перегрузка сервера параллельными запросами. Пробовал закрывать соединение при помощи `httpr.Close = true;` но вылезает ещё и `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`. Что делать?

Edit: мелкие исправления и го подсветка

Comment: что говорит `fmt.Println(err)` после `proxyUrl, err := url.Parse()`? Проверяйте все ошибки.

Comment: @biosckon обновил код. Пишет ok, а дальше саму ошибку пост запроса.

Comment: всё вроде ок должно работать проверьте что `mass[bproxy]` должен быть правильным url т.е. что ниить вроде `http://1.2.3.4:8888`

Comment: @biosckon у меня только один прокси сервер, который всегда работает, вот `https://109.254.185.60:3128`. С GET-запросом все отлично, а POST не хочет.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю ваш полный код, вот в этом виде работает

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

var (
    mass   = []string{"https://109.254.185.60:3128"}
    bproxy = 0
    host   = "https://formm.ru/handler.php"
)

func main() {
    form := url.Values{
        "username": {"Jack"},
    }

    proxyURL, err := url.Parse(mass[bproxy]) //массив с прокси серверами
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    httpClient := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL)}}

    bclose := bytes.NewBufferString(form.Encode())
    resp, err := httpClient.Post(host, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", bclose)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    text, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(text))
}
```

Удачи

Comment: Боже! Как тут все просто было! Изменил протокол `https` на `http` то есть `http://formm.ru/handler.php` и запрос успешно исполнился! Нужно было лишь убрать один символ.

Answer (score 1):

Изменил `https://formm.ru/handler.php` на `http://formm.ru/handler.php` и все успешно исполнилось!

Comment: Так `https` => `http` или `ry` => `ru`?

Comment: @Qwertiy https => http. Изменил